# DJI Windows SDK Sample Code: Cannot view FPV mode on Mavic 2 Pro

Tags: windows, dji-sdk

I am using the example code provided by [DJI for Windows SDK](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Windows-SDK9) to connect with a *Mavic 2 Pro*. I can receive the name of the drone, subscribe to update on velocities and see them. However, I cannot get any video when I click on the FPV nor use the playback, where workmode turns on green but then there is a time out when I click on reload:

> LaunchFileDataTask get files:REQUEST_TIMEOUT: Switch Mode or try again

I am using:

- Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.9.5
- Latest version of the drone and radio controller.
- Latest version of Windows SDK
- Windows Enterprise Version 1803

I have installed all the drivers and done the [Guidance to Connect with Mavic 2 Pro](https://developer.dji.com/windows-sdk/documentation/connection/Mavic2.html). I have checked on Device Manager when the controller is connected and I see the following devices:

- Vision (Interface 3)
- DJI USB Virtual COM

Also, I have uninstall and install all DJI's program, and drivers.

**Solution**

So, after several attempts and different approaches I solved the problem. I figure out that all the *drivers* provided on *DJI Assist 2 for Mavic* and *DJI Simulator* do not comply with the requirements to get the images from the Mavic. So the solution was to use [zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie/). Once on the program and the controller on and plug to the computer, select **Options->List all devices**. Now, it should be visible the driver libusb, selected and then click on **replace driver**.

Answer (score 0):

Lol I was doing beta test for DJI WSDK. didn`t encounter this. The only problem is the limited selection of drone.

Here is a checklist, cross them out 1 by 1 to rule out the issue.

1. USB Authority Configuration in UWP
2. Connection sequence
   Make sure that before connecting using your cable, your P4P V2.0 remote controller is off.

   Connect the remote controller to your computer using Micro-USB cable.

   Turn on your remote controller.

   Make sure you have not open the DJI software like DJI Assistant 2.

DJI Windows SDK Applications are not able to communicate with the aircrafts at the same time.

3 Make sure that you have installed DJI Assistant 2 and have enabled all the driver intallation while installing DJI Assistant 2.

4 WinUSB Driver

Your error seems is a connection issue. But once you pass that there are a few more thing you have to check

5. make sure you have  FFMpeg dlls in the directory

I`ll add more if I remember more. Currently, this is all I can think of

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. I have tried all the steps that you have mention. I think the same as you that is a connection issue. I guess that it should be with the Vision (Interface 3)

Comment: BTW for DJI assistant2. there is a special version for Mavic. Did you install The correct 1? Now DJI is making everything complicated.

Comment: Yes, I installed DJI Assistant 2 for Mavic 2. I also tried some suggestions from this [post](https://forum.dji.com/thread-135981-2-1.html) but not luck

Comment: So, I solved the problem. Actually I was installing an incorrect driver. On the drivers installed using the DJI Assistant 2, the libusb32 was also installed so when I used the zadig.exe this driver was not listed. So I had to select the option to show all devices, select libusb... and then replace driver

Comment: Well better to write a quick Edit/update on ur question so other ppl can find out similar issue fast